# Why `ip addr` showing inet 192.168.122.1/24?

Tags: linux, ip

My local ip address is : 10.102.42.102, but i don't understand the rest of the address. Can someone explain why ?

```
root@HitHiFitHai:~# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 78:24:af:36:06:cb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.102.42.102/8 brd 10.255.255.255 scope global eth1
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::7a24:afff:fe36:6cb/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
link/ether 56:9c:21:33:37:c8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: macvtap0@eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
link/ether 52:54:00:d3:46:e2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fed3:46e2/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
 root@HitHiFitHai:~#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
link/ether 56:9c:21:33:37:c8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This is a "default" bridge network created by libvirt,for give network to virtual machines(nat if remind good)
192.168.122/1 is a class C network with 255.255.255.0 netmask(24 bit)

Comment: How to check that address is up or not ?. Possible solution is `ping 192.168.122.1` right ?

Comment: ifconfig virbr0  |grep -w UP,if report something is up,otherwise is down

Comment: Okay, thanks :)
One more question, What would be the equivalent local ip created by `libvirt`. And how to access it from same computer ?.

Comment: Libvirt create "virtual ip" for natted machines,and you cannot access directly as i know,this is possible only using a bridged network